# jstree display improperly after creating node

Tags: jquery, jstree

I am creating a new node in I using jstree and it displays the node incorrectly.

The two pictures below are pictures of nodes being out of place after being created.

They are inside a table inside a div.  The div is scrollable and the node moves with the scroll upon initial creation.

Once I deselect the node, it goes to the correct place.

[Picture of node out of place.](http://i.imgur.com/EfvnE) "Node out of place after being created"

[Picture of node out of place.](http://i.imgur.com/i054N) "Another node out of place"

Apparently this occurs for rename as well.

Answer (score 0):

Modified _show_input function in jstree.js as follows:

```
h2 = obj.children('a:first').after(
    $("<input />", { 
        "value" : t,
        "class" : "jstree-rename-input",
        // "size" : t.length,
        "css" : {
            "padding" : "0",
            "border" : "1px solid silver",
            "left"  : (rtl ? "auto" : (w1 + w2 + 4) + "px"),
            "right" : (rtl ? (w1 + w2 + 4) + "px" : "auto"),
            "top" : "0px",
            "height" : (this.data.core.li_height - 2) + "px",
            "lineHeight" : (this.data.core.li_height - 2) + "px",
            "width" : "150px" // will be set a bit further down
        },
        "blur" : $.proxy(function () {
            var i = obj.children(".jstree-rename-input"),
                v = i.val();
            if(v === "") { v = t; }
            h1.remove();
            i.remove(); // rollback purposes
            this.set_text(obj,t); // rollback purposes
            this.rename_node(obj, v);
            callback.call(this, obj, v, t);
            obj.css("position","");
        }, this),
        "keyup" : function (event) {
            var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
            if(key == 27) { this.value = t; this.blur(); return; }
            else if(key == 13) { this.blur(); return; }
            else {
                h2.width(Math.min(h1.text("pW" + this.value).width(),w));
            }
        },
        "keypress" : function(event) {
            var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
            if(key == 13) { return false; }
        }
    })
).siblings(".jstree-rename-input");
```

The first line was changed to append the input object after the first anchor element in obj, which is an LI element.  The last line was changed to return all siblings with class .jstree-rename-input.

Also removed absolute positioning on the input and the obj.